# Redirect All URL to SSL, Except for X

Tags: linux, nginx, ssl, https

I run NGINX on Vesta CP. There are two separate files `nginx.conf` and `snginx.conf`. Each has a server block in it. I redirect entire sites to SSL. To do this I add a `return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;` to the `nginx.conf`, and then I fully configure the `sningx.conf` for caching and location blocks and everything else.

I do have one domain which is partial SSL/non-SSL. In these files I for not 301, but instead I 301 a location block, like this:

```
location ~ ^/(wp-login.php|wp-admin|wp-login|shop|product|my-account|checkout-2|order-pay|order-received|add-payment-method|cart) {
return 301 https://domain.com$request_uri;}
```

And in the SSL block I exclude:

```
location ~ ^(?!/(wp-login.php|wp-admin|wp-login|shop|product|my-account|checkout-2|order-pay|order-received|add-payment-method|cart)) {
return  301 http://sergerpepper.com$request_uri;}
```

I have a need to have one URL available on both SSL and non-SSL, with everything else on SSL. This url is the sitemap. So both of these would work:

```
http://example.com/sitemap_index.xml

https://example.com/sitemap_index.xml
```

But any other URL would only be on SSL. With my above previous redirect method, I can point a URL at HTTP or Exclude it for HTTPS, but not both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your https server block should not redirect anything to http, as you don't need that in this situation.

Your http server block should redirect everything, except the URL in question:

```
server {
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 80;
    server_name .example.com;
    root /srv/www/example.com;

    location = /sitemap_index.xml {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri$is_args$args;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hrm, but if I use my http block to redirect to https, then my NGINX config needs to be in https because that is read by the browser once redirected? I only ask because all of my configuration is in my snginx.conf file: ' gzip_vary on;
 add_header Vary "Accept-Encoding";
 add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
 proxy_hide_header Expires;
 proxy_hide_header Cache-Control;
 expires 30d;
 etag off;
 proxy_cache_valid 30d;
 add_header Pragma public;
 add_header Cache-Control "public";'

Comment: I run VestaCP which adds some of its own language in here, but this is what I am currently looking at using your solution but still keeping a majority of my config in snginx.conf: http://prntscr.com/ab4h8y