# How to forward all http requests to https without breaking letsencrypt with nginx

Tags: nginx, 301-redirect, lets-encrypt

I'm using Nginx to serve as a reverse proxy for Rstudio server and Shiny server for the purposes of securing the connection to these services.  I'm using Letencrypt for free signed certs.

I have this entry for letsencrypt to verify I am who I say I am.

```
server { 
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.html index.htm;

  # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
  server_name mydomain.com;

  location ~ /.well-known {

    allow all;
  }
}
```

I also have another `server` to listen on 443 and `proxy_redirect` to my servers.  Everything there works fine.  What I want to do is have something like

```
server {
listen 80;
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

but I think this will break letsencrypt so how do I have the above without breaking letsencrypt verification?

Comment: So basically you want to redirect all requests except for the `/.well-known`

Comment: @Drifter104 yes exactly.  I'm guessing it's really simple if you know what you're doing but I don't fall in that category.

Comment: You just need to move the return Take a look at this question and answers. Different context same process/answer http://serverfault.com/questions/761501/redirect-all-url-to-ssl-except-for-x

Comment: Are you sure you need this verification server for letsencrypt? I use it myself, and every time I renew my certificates I have to stop nginx(!) for lertsencrypt to use port 80 for the renewal process. All my certificates work fine.

Comment: @JosefScript well I guess that's the key is that I don't want to have to mess with nginx everytime I need to renew.  I believe you're right though that I could just redirect everything except for when it's time to renew.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My working configuration for this is:

```
server {
         listen 80;
         listen [::]:80;
         server_name example.com www.example.com;

         root /srv/www/empty;

         include includes/letsencrypt;

         location / {
                 return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
         }
}
```

where `/etc/nginx/includes/letsencrypt` is Ansible managed and contains:

```
location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
         try_files $uri =404;
}
```

and `/srv/www/empty` is an otherwise empty directory, which only contains files when Let's Encrypt is being used to issue a challenge (with `--webroot`).

Let's Encrypt is then run with:

```
letsencrypt certonly --webroot -w /srv/www/empty -d example.com -d www.example.com
```